# In Apache Ignite when data is partitioned equally how ignite decides on which node data should be send

Tags: java, ignite

I want to know how ignite partitions works internally,How ignite decides on which node data should be send

Answer (score 1):

Each key can be mapped to partition using hashcode. At the same time, partitions can be mapped to nodes using Affinity Function:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation#section-affinity-function